# Does Eclipse Che have an option to set user defined themes for the workspace and dashboard

Tags: themes, eclipse-che

Is there an settings option in Eclipse Che to set the required theme for eclipse che?
Currently I see an option to set different themes for a workspace.
What I am looking for is any settings to set a default theme [other than the dark theia theme] for any workspace created by any users.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, dashboard has only one theme available.

As far as I know, there is no option for the admin to configure the default Theia theme for each user without modifying Theia editor image.
But each user should be able to configure the default Theia theme at their global scope (for all their workspaces).